# Limiting Depth of Image to Specific Set

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, colors

I'm tying to convert an image to a specific pre-determined set. Despite several attempts I still get colors in the final image which aren't in the palette I provide. I'm using the code below and filling `availableColors` with my colors.

```
private static Image GetImageInPalette(string imagePath, List<System.Windows.Media.Color> availableColors) {

        BitmapImage bmpSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));
        BitmapPalette colorPalette = new BitmapPalette(availableColors);
        FormatConvertedBitmap bmpWithPalette = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bmpSource, PixelFormats.Indexed8, colorPalette, 0);

        var encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpWithPalette));
        Image destinationImage;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            destinationImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        return destinationImage;
    }
```

It' as though the image is still using some variant of nearest neighbour.

Comment: Did you specify all 256 possible colors?  "No" could be inferred I guess.

Comment: Thanks Hans. So if I don't provide 256 unique colors, the rest will be 'filled in'? I want to take an image and reduce it to a maximum palette of 31 pre-defined colors. Is this possible?

Comment: An easy way around this is to fill the palette's remaining entries with copies of your index #0 colour. Or write your own nearest colour match algorithm that uses an array and not a palette.